# How to raise a seek to event for a Flash MediaElement using iframe?

Tags: flash, iframe, mediaelement, flashvars

How can a seek event be raised to a Flash MediaElement, starting from an embed code with defaults flashvars. Such as:

```
<embed id="me_flash_0"
       name="me_flash_0" play="true" loop="false" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" 
       wmode="transparent" 
       allowscriptaccess="always" 
       allowfullscreen="true" 
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       pluginspage="//www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
       src="/dl/player/Fallback/flashmediaelement.swf" 
       flashvars="id=me_flash_0&amp;isvideo=true&amp;autoplay=true&amp;preload=none&amp;width=968&amp;startvolume=0.8&amp;timerrate=250&amp;flashstreamer=&amp;height=580&amp;pseudostreamstart=start&amp;autohideinterval=5&amp;islive=false&amp;smoothing=true" 
      width="968" height="580" nanclass="mejs-shim">
```

If a seek event cannot be raised directly, what about an expensive player rerendering to a specific start time?

Additionally what are the default possible values of flashvars?

What is `nanclass="mejs-shim"` a shim for what?

Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886564/how-can-i-read-embedded-flash-video-time-parameter-or-events

Comment: Usually the SWF must already have the necessary code within that tells it to send/respond to Javascript. Who made the `flashmediaelements.swf` and did they say JS/HTML responses were included in the SWF as capabilities? No idea about the shims though

Comment: The shim is actually the javascript layer sitting on top of the media element. Calling the shim functions carries out the corresponding action in the media element, such as seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found the answer. Without accessing the SWF, interacting directly with the MediaElement shim, [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) allows the media to be controlled.
The functionalities can be accessed using the embed tag id and one of the functions declared in the media element.
So in order to seek through the media using the shim `window.me_flash_0.setCurrentTime(30);` is enough to seek 30s within the media.